# Setting up mstest.exe with Jenkins for a C# Core 2.0

Tags: c#, jenkins, .net-core, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to set up a Jenkins server for my C# Project. The Server currently runs on my localhost as I'm testing it out.

So far, I've managed to restore NuGet packages, and build the project, using 2 steps in the Build config.

Now, I'm trying to have it execute our unit tests. The tests are made using Microsoft's own test framework.

I initially tried to use the plugin to run the tests, and also set it up using a windows bat file, both result in the same problem.

The dll assembly cannot be found.

My bat command looks like this:
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /resultsfile:"%WORKSPACE%\Results.trx" /testcontainer:"%WORKSPACE%\msTests\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\msTest.dll" /nologo`, the result being: Test file not found.

I assume this is because Jenkins removes the build assemblies on success? How can I disable that? Or something else I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using dotnet core you should be using the dotnet test command.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test?tabs=netcore21

Comment: Thats so nice and simple. Why did that take me so long to find. Thank you!